# Get a value from a database in VIsual Studio

Tags: vb.net

I am using visual studio and programming in VB, and now I am interested in implementing a database to my solutions. 
Thus far, what I have done is the creation of a connection

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=C:\Users\WALTER\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\database_try\database_try2.sdf"

Dim cn As SqlClient.SqlConnection

cn = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)
```

The problem is I have looked and searched on the web about the way to get a value of a certain variable created in a table in a simple manner, but I do not get it.
In a simple way, If I crate a table

```
Name     Number
Walter     123
```

What I want to know is: How do I get the name or the number from the previously created table, and save it in a variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: VBA is very different from VB.Net and should not be confused when tagging your questions.

Comment: Sorry. If you just google, you will find the answer

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method.

Take a look at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the answer just by using Google. Do you know how to write `SQL`? Are you having problems with the syntax? Narrowing down the problem will really help people to solve your issues.

I'm also not sure if you're using `MS-SQL Server` or `MySQL`?

Either way, the best way to do this is the following:

```
Dim Da As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT Name FROM myTable WHERE Number = ?", cn)
Da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Number", SqlClientDataType.Integer).Value = i
Dim Ds As New DataSet
Da.Fill(Ds)

Dim myVar as String = Ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Name")
```

(This is totally free-hand, don't have an IDE available to test but this is roughly correct.